# Accidentally turned home directory in ubuntu to read only. How to turn this back?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, filesystems

I accidentally turned turned my home directory in ubuntu to read only.

```
sudo chown -RW $USER: $HOME
```

Comment: I think you did something different, because `chown` has no `-W` option, and I get: `chown: invalid option -- 'W'` and nothing is changed.

Comment: Options of chown can be seen at https://ss64.com/bash/chown.html

Answer (score 1):

If the command `ls -la` shows the dir owner to be the correct user:

```
sudo chmod 755 /path/to/home/
```

which should do the trick.

If the command `ls -la` shows the user to be root or not the right user:

```
sudo chown username:username /path/to/home
sudo chmod 755 /path/to/home
```

If the files within were changed as well then use the recursive option -R with those commands.

Comment: Michael thanks for responding. ls -al showed correct user. So I used sudo chmod 755 /path/to/home/ . But I got response as 'sudo chmod 755 /path/to/home/ (should do the trick)'

Comment: @KRISHNAI Did it worked for you or not. Sorry the comment above is not clear.

Comment: NO it didn't work. I think file system has crashed. So I sent my laptop for repair.